# Azure Service Fabric Activation Error 7148

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a service fabric cluster which hosts numerous applications. One of the applications has a service type where the service is created, runs for a bit, and then is deleted. Everything works great, but the cluster virtually always has its state set to error because there will be a few of these in the "Unhealthy evaluations" section.

> Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='CodePackageActivation:Code:EntryPoint'.
>   There was an error during CodePackage activation.The service host terminated with exit code:7148

I've wrapped both the program's main and RunAsync in exception handlers, but never see anything in analytics. Is there any way to look up what exit code 7148 means? Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

7148 is a general error code that indicates that something failed in SF in the process of setting up or activating your service's host process. So that's the reason that you're not seeing any errors or exceptions - your code is never getting a chance to run.

Examples of things I've seen that led to 7148:

- The exe was not actually a windows exe due to corruption
- The service's manifest had a reference to a cert or some other pre-req like an endpoint that was incorrectly configured (like a port that was already in use or the wrong thumbprint for a cert)
- Something blew up inside Windows that cause the process creation to fail, like a failure to correctly configure host networking for a container

Most of the times when I see this I have to look at the windows error logs to see what's really happening. The SF folks are also trying to capture more common causes of failures and reporting them as better health errors rather than relying on 7148.

Comment: Speaking from experience, 7148 can also be caused by the cluster node / VM running out of memory.